# Grep not working with variables, even with quotes

Tags: shell-script, grep, quoting

`name=$(echo "$FILENAME" | grep -E '*\.(eng|por|pt-BR)\.*')`

Why this line doesn't work?

if I do

`echo "Test (2013).1080p.por.mkv" | grep -E "*\.(eng|por)\.*"`

It works, I tried with "" without " and with ' in my script and it seems like it's not getting piped to grep. I don't know why? I'm using bash.

`FILENAME="Test (2013).1080p.por.mkv"`

I want to grab only .por. or .eng in a file

Comment: Are you literally running that first line as-is? Are you sure that the FILENAME variable isn't empty?

Comment: In what way does it _not work_? Is `$name` empty? How do you check it? Do you get an error?, What do you get if you replace `grep -E ...` with `sed -n l`? What do you expect to achieve with that command? What about doing `case $FILENAME in (*.eng.* | *.por.* | *.pt-BR.*) ...; esac`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas no error, it's just printed the entire variable. Yes `$name` is empty and I set `$FILENAME` before it with `FILENAME="Test (2013) [HDTV-720p].bluray.1080p.por.mkv"
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is the tool to print (whole) lines matching a pattern. It's not appropriate to extract parts of a string (though some `grep` implementations have `-o<n>` or `-o` options that can be used in some cases for that).

Here, you can use `expr`:

```
name=$(expr " $FILENAME" : '.*\.\(eng\)\.' '|' \
            " $FILENAME" : '.*\.\(por\)\.' '|' \
            " $FILENAME" : '.*\.\(pt-PT\)\.')
```

(for `foo.por.eng.bar`, gives priority to `eng` over `por` over `pt-PT`).

Some `expr` implementations like GNU `expr` also support:

```
name=$(expr " $FILENAME" : '.*\.\(eng\|por\|pt-PT\)\.')
```

(here returns the rightmost occurrence if there are several in the filename)

With GNU `grep` or compatible:

```
name=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$FILENAME" |
    grep -Po '\.\K(eng|por|pt-PT)(?=\.)' |
    head -n 1
)
```

(returns first occurrence, replace `head` with `tail` for last)

Or you could use your shell's `case` construct and not run any command at all:

```
case $FILENAME in
  (*.por.*) name=por;;
  (*.eng.*) name=eng;;
  (*.pt-PT.*) name=pt-PT;;
esac
```

With `bash`:

```
re='\.(por|eng|pt-PT)\.'
[[ $FILENAME =~ $re ]]
name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

(first occurrence. With `zsh`, replace `BASH_REMATCH` with `match`)

Comment: Why it's not appropriated if it seems everyone uses it?

Comment: one point is that it will not filter correctly, it will catch literals too like "[HDTV-720p].bluray.1080p.(eng|por|pt-BR).mkv"

Comment: thanks! `expr` seems also much easier to learn and use, and it worked both in situations where I had "eng" words in my filename but the a .por.srt file. It had a 100% success in those kind of tests so thank you so much.

Comment: what if I wanted to apply this to a variable that is a directory?

Comment: @Freedo, not sure what you mean, that's just string manipulation, it doesn't care whether that string is a path to a directory or any other type of file.

Comment: I mean what if I wanted to match the files inside a folder with your expr? I tried adding ls before the variable but I get permission denied error somehow lol. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @Freedo, still not sure what you mean. Maybe something like `for FILENAME in some/dir/*.mkv; do name=$(expr...); done`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file names are like `Some name.por.mkv`, with the final extension fixed, you could use the POSIX shell string operations, too:

```
$ echo "$FILENAME"
Test (2013).1080p.por.mkv
$ x=${FILENAME%.mkv}; echo "${x##*.}"
por
```

Here, `${var%.mkv}` removes the trailing `.mkv`, and `${var##*.}` removes everything up to the (now) last dot. You could change the first expansion to handle other extensions by changing  `.mkv` to just `.*`.